# Reference request - obtaining finite simple groups from algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, finite-fields

I'm looking for references for the following statements, which I believe are true:

Let $G$ be a simply connected simple linear algebraic group over a finite field $k$ of cardinality $q\ge 4$. Let $Z\le G$ be its center. Then

1. $Z(k) = Z(G(k))$
2. $G(k)/Z(G(k)) = G(k)/Z(k)$ is simple (as a finite group).
3. The derived subgroup of $(G/Z)(k)$ is simple.
4. $Z((G/Z)(k)) = 1$

If some of the statements above aren't true, what is the "correct" statement?

Comment: R.W. Carter's book ``Simple groups of Lie type'' (1972) might contain what you seek.